# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in shell script

Tags: shell, syntax-error

This is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
MONITOR=$(free -m| grep Mem)
MEM_TOTAL=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $2 }')
MEM_USED=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $3 }')
MEM_FREE=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $4 }')
MEM_CACHE=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $5 }')
MEM_BUFFER=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $6 }')
declare -i MEM_UTIL=($MEM_TOTAL-($MEM_FREE+$MEM_BUFFER+$MEM_CACHE))
echo "$MEM_UTIL"
```

I got syntax errors such as

```
./memory_shell.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./memory_shell.sh: line 15: `declare -i MEM_UTIL=($MEM_TOTAL-($MEM_FREE+$MEM_BUFFER+$MEM_CACHE))'
```

How can I fix it. I have 0 knowledge in shell scripting

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend

Answer (score 3):

Just to record my issue with exactly this error message.
Turns out my scripts were DOS text files not Unix text files (as a result of a restore). 
DOS2Unix fix scripts and they ran fine with out this error.
Your mileage may vary ....

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put quotes around the argument to `declare -i` as it takes one argument.

```
declare -i MEM_UTIL="($MEM_TOTAL-($MEM_FREE+$MEM_BUFFER+$MEM_CACHE))"
```

As you're using awk anyway, you may as well use it fully. The following does the same operation in awk:

```
#!/bin/sh
free -m | awk '/Mem/ {print($2 - ($4 + $5 + $6));}'
```

Awk can match the line for you as you are doing with grep and perform operations on the fields in the matched record. So rather than forking a number of subprocesses, you can fork one to process the output of the free command.

Comment: How can I get buffer and cache? `MEM_BUFFER=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $6 }')` is getting as buffer/cache. I have no idea to get separately. Actually this script getting `MEM_CACHE=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $5 }')` shared memory

Comment: If you need more parts parsed you will need to either return multiple values from the awk script and use the shell `read` function or continue with the exisiting script but use quotes to group the expression into a single argument. You've evidently only posted a fraction of the script so only you know which parts you will require.